# if i change my bank password will venmo lose access to the bank?

Tags: banking

After I learned that Venmo uses Plaid and monitors all transactions, I wanted to remove all access to the bank, but Venmo decided to put account on lock preventing me from doing that, and to remove the lock I'm being asked to send them more information. However, If I recall correctly plaid uses plain credentials, so If I were to change my bank password would that end Venmo bank account link?

Comment: Does your bank use OAuth for the link? This may be a question for your bank.

Comment: I'll chat with bank on monday

Comment: @MuhammadUmer What did your bank say?

Comment: i talked to chat who seemed to had no idea, so I've emailed them